# Jquery mobile pagePage -> live('pageinit') don't working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to make a page transition using "pageChange":

```
$.mobile.changePage('new.html', { transition: "none"});
```

when the page loads, I want to executa a function. For this, I added this code in "new.js":

```
$('#new-page').live('pageinit', function(event) { ... });
```

The problem is when the caller page opens the new page the previous function don't run, I have to reload the page to run it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do, but have you tried `on` instead of `live`? (`live` is deprecated)

Comment: The event binding looks good. are you sure that 1) the page does not have the id "new-page" 2) you referenced new.js in the header of the originial page (NOT in new.html). JQuery mobile will ignore the header of pages it changePage to.

Comment: Your binding to the wrong [page event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html), try `pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow` (or one of the other page change events, it all depends when exactly you want the event to fire).

Answer (score 0):

pageinit is only called once for a page, when it is initially loaded into the DOM.  Subsequent navigations to the page won't force it to reload into the DOM (unless you specify the option on the changePage method)

> when the page loads, I want to executa a function.

I suspect what you're actually after is pageshow or pagebeforeshow though?

Comment: The error was that I didn't include "new-page.js" os the main page. Problem solved.